# Pycharm Python Unused Imports For Subclasses Imports Although They Are Implicitly Used

Tags: python, pycharm

In my following code, I have a base class in python and a few sub classes that inherits from this class.
Every sub class has a convert function, and a should_convert function.
What I am trying to do is iterate through all sub classes, and if the sub class should convert, then perform convert later on.
Code looks something like this

```
    from {file path to converter a} import ConverterA
    from {file path to converter b} import ConverterB
    all_converters = [converter(input_path, server_version) for converter in AbstractConverter.__subclasses__()]
    relevant_converters = [converter for converter in all_converters if converter.should_convert()]
    for converter in relevant_converters:
        converter.convert()
```

So in order to find sub classes, I had to import them (else it would not recognise the sub classes)

But Pycharm says those imports are not used (where it is used implicitly in sub_classes method).
Any help on how to make imports marked as used? or maybe this approach to the code is not a good practice and other approach should be used?

Thanks.

Comment: If you import ConverterA, ConverterB explicitly, consider using them as `[ConverterA, ConverterB]` instead of `AbstractConverter.__subclasses__()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a comment suppressing the inspection of pycharm. Either just add the comment by hand:

```
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import os
```

In above code the import os will not be displayed as unused anymore.

Or you can hover over the line, so pycharm displays the "Unused import statement" dialog, then click `More Actions...`, click the little arrow icon next to `Optimize Import`. Finally, select `Suppress for a statement`. It will then automatically add the comment `# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences`.

Here is a link to the documentation of PyCharm about suppressing inspections (with screenshots): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-in-editor

Comment: Thanks! the # noinspection does the work for me